# Count elements and find the maximum

Tags: sql, hive

I've got a table like this:

```
+-----+-----+-----+
| uid | aid | tid |
+-----+-----+-----+
| 1   | 6   | 7   |
+-----+-----+-----+
| 2   | 6   | 7   |
+-----+-----+-----+
| 3   | 5   | 7   |
+-----+-----+-----+
| 4   | 5   | 7   |
+-----+-----+-----+
| 5   | 5   | 7   |
+-----+-----+-----+
```

I'm expecting to find, for each tid, which aid has more elements.
For example, i know that tid 7 has 2 times aid 6, like this.

+

```
-----+-----+-------+
| tid | aid | count |
+-----+-----+-------+
| 7   | 6   | 2     |
+-----+-----+-------+
| 7   | 5   | 3     |
+-----+-----+-------+
```

The final result I'm expecting is 7 5 3, because I want the maximum count.

I've achieved my desired result using two queries:

```
CREATE TABLE temp AS
SELECT tid, aid, count(aid) as c
FROM startingtable
GROUP BY tid, aid
ORDER BY tid, aid;
```

and then

```
CREATE TABLE result AS
select a.tid, a.aid, a.c
from temp a
inner join
(SELECT tid, max(c) as m
FROM temp
GROUP BY tid) b
on a.tid = b.tid and a.c = b.m
order by tid;
```

I need it to be functional using just one query. How would you do that?

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to use *self-join* with subquery.

```
CREATE TABLE temp AS
SELECT t1.*
FROM (
    SELECT tid, 
           aid,
           count(aid) as cnt       
    FROM startingtable
    GROUP BY tid, aid
) t1 JOIN (
    SELECT tid,
           MAX(cnt) maxcnt
    FROM (
        SELECT tid, 
           aid, 
           count(aid) as cnt
        FROM startingtable
        GROUP BY tid, aid
    ) t2 
    GROUP BY tid
)t2 ON t1.tid = t2.tid and t1.cnt = t2.maxcnt
```

another way you can try to use `CTE` with `Row_number` window function to insert your data to the table.

```
WITH CTE AS (
    SELECT tid, 
       aid, 
       count(aid) as cnt
    FROM startingtable
    GROUP BY tid, aid
)
insert into #temp (tid,aid,cnt) 
select t2.tid,
       t2.aid,
       t2.cnt
from (
    SELECT *,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY tid order by cnt desc) rn
    FROM CTE 
) t2
where rn = 1
```

Comment: This works like a charm. A question though: i tried several times subqueries, and they didn't work. Your subquery is working flawlessly. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

Use `rank()` analytic function:

```
select tid, aid, c
from
(
select tid, aid, c,
       rank() over(partition by tid order by c desc) rnk --max(c) per tid ranked 1
from
(
SELECT tid, 
       aid, 
       count(aid) as c
FROM startingtable
GROUP BY tid, aid
)s
)s where rnk=1;
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try the following, this seems to be a bit simpler than the other answers, but I could be missing something.

```
SELECT * FROM ( 
    SELECT tid, aid, count(*) 
    FROM test  
    GROUP BY tid, aid 
    ORDER BY count(*) DESC) 
WHERE rownum = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

just try this:

```
SELECT tid, aid, COUNT(*) AS elCount FROM startingtable
GROUP BY tid, aid
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to express the logic uses window functions:

```
SELECT tid, aid, cnt
FROM (SELECT tid, aid, COUNT(*) as cnt,
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY tid ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC) as seqnum   -- or maybe RANK() 
      FROM startingtable t
      GROUP BY tid, aid
     ) t
WHERE seqnum = 1;
```

Only one level of subquery/CTE is needed for the logic.